# Create curved transparent gradient on photo

Tags: flutter, flutter-image

I want to create this filter effect:

[image]

Now my image looks like this:

[image]

Is there any best practice or a package that does that? Or do I have to create my own bézier curve for that?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It somehow depends on the size of your images as well. the image on behind ratio should be vertically bigger than your UI component. and if we use the `BoxFit.cover` it will cover its parent. vertically will exceed the parent (so the head of the girl is being cut) and horizontally will cover. For this behind image I applied a little blur effect as well, you can customize the effect to any way you want.

For the image on top to achieve the white semi-transparent overlay, you can put a container on top and clip it the way you want with `ClipPath` with a `CustomClipper`:

```
import 'dart:ui';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: const MyHomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyHomePage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<MyHomePage> createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return const Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: SizedBox(
          width: 600,
          height: 400,
          child: BezierBlurImage(imagePath: 'assets/test_image.png'),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class BezierBlurImage extends StatelessWidget {
  const BezierBlurImage({Key? key, required this.imagePath}) : super(key: key);

  final String imagePath;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return LayoutBuilder(
      builder: (context, constraints) {
        final width = constraints.maxWidth;
        final height = constraints.maxHeight;
        return Stack(
          fit: StackFit.expand,
          children: [
            Container(
              width: width,
              height: height,
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                image: DecorationImage(
                  image: AssetImage(imagePath),
                  colorFilter: ColorFilter.mode(
                    Colors.blue[300]!,
                    BlendMode.modulate,
                  ),
                  fit: BoxFit.cover,
                ),
              ),
              child: BackdropFilter(
                filter: ImageFilter.blur(sigmaX: 2, sigmaY: 2),
                child: Container(
                  color: Colors.black.withOpacity(0),
                ),
              ),
            ),
            Center(
              child: Container(
                width: 200,
                height: 250,
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  color: Colors.blueAccent,
                  image: DecorationImage(
                    image: AssetImage(imagePath),
                    fit: BoxFit.cover,
                  ),
                ),
                child: ClipPath(
                  clipper: BezierClipper(),
                  child: Container(
                    color: Colors.white.withOpacity(0.4),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        );
      },
    );
  }
}

class BezierClipper extends CustomClipper<Path> {
  @override
  Path getClip(Size size) {
    final width = size.width;
    final height = size.height;
    return Path()
      ..moveTo(0, 0)
      ..lineTo(width, 0)
      ..conicTo(0, 0, 0, height * 0.6, 0.3);
  }

  @override
  bool shouldReclip(covariant CustomClipper<Path> oldClipper) => true;
}
```

[image]